# Spring Hibernate Saving Entities in Test Not Persisting

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HibernateConfigTest.class})
@Transactional
@Sql(scripts = {"api_routes.sql",
                "profile.sql",
                "status.sql",
                "user.sql",
                "game_token.sql",
                "game.sql",
                "message.sql"},
     config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED),
     executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "delete_data.sql", 
     executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class GameDaoTest {
    @Autowired
    private GameDao gameDao;

    @Test
    public void getGetRecentGames() {
        Game game = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            game = new Game(i + 1000);
            game.setStartedAt(DateUtils.getCurrentUTCDate());
            gameDao.save("game", game);
        }

        List<Game> recentGames = gameDao.getRecentGames(1000);
        assertNotNull(recentGames);
        assertEquals(1000, recentGames.size());
    }
}
```

When I get to the line `List<Game> recentGames = gameDao.getRecentGames(1000);` hibernate prints out all of the insert statements. Unfortunately, when the games are retrieved, none of the ones I inserted are retrieved. Is there any way to retrieve those games? Maybe a better question would be how do I put those inserts in their own transaction so they are persisted for the subsequent methods?

Here is the AbstractDao that GameDao extends:

```
public class AbstractDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }

    public void save(Object entity) {
        getSession().save(entity);
    }

    public void save(String entityName, Object entity) {
        getSession().save(entityName, entity);
    }

    public void persist(Object entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }
}
```

The persist method throws an exception for some detached entity reason that I am not familiar with.

Comment: Could you show the gameDao.save() method?

Comment: @Bruno_Ferreira added the save method

Comment: User has EntityManager, yet throws away portability needlessly by extracting a Session and executing (equivalent) methods on it?

Comment: Please provide us the source code for your `GameDao`, since we need to see the configuration (i.e., presence and configuration of annotations such as `@Transactional`), transaction demarcation, implementation details, etc. Otherwise, we're just playing a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `flush` on your session before calling `getRecentGames`. If that method is executing a custom query, as opposed to using one of Hibernate's session methods, it's going directly against the database -- but since your `save` hasn't yet been synced with the underlying database, the data isn't there. You don't actually need to do a true commit as long as Hibernate can see the data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    game = new Game(i + 1000);
    game.setStartedAt(DateUtils.getCurrentUTCDate());
    gameDao.save("game", game);
}
gameDao.flush(); // calls getSession().flush()

List<Game> recentGames = gameDao.getRecentGames(1000);
// call assert methods as needed
```

Comment: Since flushing didn't work, please provide us the implementation for `getRecentGames()`.